# WP_Query returns different results from get_posts()

Tags: wp-query, page-template, child-theme, child-pages

So I have two code snippets, trying to get the child pages of the current page. The current page is "Sample", and the following code lives in page-sample.php.

The first snippet uses get_posts()

```
$args = array(
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'post_type'   => 'page', 
                'post_status' => 'any' 
            );
$children = get_posts( $args );
// $children = get_children( $args ); //this also works,btw

foreach($children as $child){
    setup_postdata( $child );
    echo "<h1>" .  $child->post_title . "</h1>";
}
```

This correctly displays the child posts.

The second snippet uses a new WP_Query object

```
$args = array(
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'post_type'   => 'page', 
                // 'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'any' 
            );
$child_pages_query= new WP_Query(args);
// echo $child_pages_query->post_count; // wrong answer already!
if ($child_pages_query->have_posts()){
    while($child_pages_query->have_posts()){
        $child_pages_query->the_post();
        echo "<h1> " . $post->post_title . " </h1>";
        }
}
```

This **incorrectly** displays **all posts** . No pages, just posts.

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

1. No plugins are installed
2. I commented out all parent theme code, including header,footer, till it was a bare html page, even though I couldn't see anything in header.php or footer.php that could be affecting this.

Now the funny part is changing the WP_Query args doesn't seem to be making any difference. Always, all posts. WP_Query works on other pages.

Any help would be appreciated. Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that `get_posts` calls `WP_Query` internally

Comment: You are missing a `$` before `args` in `$child_pages_query= new WP_Query(args);`. It should be `$child_pages_query= new WP_Query($args);`. Have you enabled `WP_DEBUG`?

Comment: @czerspalace you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `$` before args in

```
$child_pages_query= new WP_Query(args);
```

It should be

```
$child_pages_query= new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe I spent so many hours trying to figure this out -_- . You're right of course, and the query is working fine now. Much thanks! But why doesn't php throw an error for this one? Does "args" without the $ also mean something?

Comment: Do you have WP_DEBUG enabled? If you enable you should see the error

Comment: It would throw a warning/notice not an error

Comment: No I don't. This would be my first wordpress/php project. I will definitely check it out now.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `$` on your `WP_Query` args array:

```
$child_pages_query= new WP_Query(args);
```

Should be:

```
$child_pages_query= new WP_Query($args);
```

This should show up as a PHP warnings/notice in the error logs, and is preventable with standard debugging and development practices.

Answer (score -3):

In your WP_Query code instead of

```
echo $post->post_title;
```

Try

```
echo $child_pages_query->post->post_title;
```